# Simple bevel between two vertex, vertex not connected?

Tags: vertices, bevel

I am very new to blender, what i am trying to do is nice bevel on each corner (i menage to do only one side with glitch on the other)

[image]

What i noticed the corner on the right side looks like it is connected to the bottom

[image]

But the left one looks diffrent on selection (not connected to bottom vertex?):

[image]

I would appreciate an explanation what happens here, and how to fix it to make bevel on both sides.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have 2 overlapping vertices?

Comment: Since the edge is going up to the vertex, there obviously must be another vertex in the same location which connects to it. Hit A to select all, then M > Merge > By Distance and the two vertices should be merged into one.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann it indeed solve the problem, thank you very much! Would you like to make it as separate answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Sure, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the edge is going up to the vertex, there obviously must be another vertex in the same location which connects to it. Hit A to select all, then M > Merge > By Distance and the two vertices should be merged into one.